# Voting on suggested tag synonyms

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

I created a suggestion for the tag synonym 'mg.metric-geometry' <--- 'classical-geometry' two weeks ago. However, it appears to have received no votes yet, up or down. Is this delay to be expected? If not, what is wrong?

Comment: I disagree with this particular suggestion

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The tag synonym voting mechanism doesn't really work well for any site but the largest ones. The requirements to be able to vote on a synonym are very high, and the visibility of proposed synonyms is almost nonexistant.

I'd suggest to propose synonyms on meta and have the moderators create them once a consensus is reached. The public discussion usually makes sure that the synonyms make sense, and it is far more efficient than voting on synonyms in most cases.

Comment: Posting on meta increases the visibility, too. So the chances of some people voting on the tag synonym are higher if people see the synonym mentioned on meta. On meta.MSE there is a [separate thread](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1363/tag-merging-and-synonyms) dedicated to tag synonyms. It's up to MO community to decide whether something like that would be a good idea.